# How to use SPICE?

Tags: 11.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I tried to use SPICE with qemu to use with a Windows XP virtual machine on Ubuntu 11.04/64 bit. I followed these instructions:

http://docs.cslabs.clarkson.edu/wiki/SPICE

I ended with these Problems:

- the newly compiled version of qemu conflicted with libvirt (apparmor)
- as a result I could not use virt-manager
- starting the VM without virt-manager was possible, but I did not have a network connection inside the VM

Is there a reliable way to install SPICE in ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another topic? Just use Xen ;  the explanation is in the post you made a few hours ago: [Best way to access a Windows-XP virtual machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60528/best-way-to-access-a-windows-xp-virtual-machine)

But anyway, if you want SPICE specifically here is the [installation method](http://bderzhavets.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/setup-kvmqemuspice-on-ubuntu-11-04-via-ppaserge-hallynspice2/): http://bderzhavets.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/setup-kvmqemuspice-on-ubuntu-11-04-via-ppaserge-hallynspice2/

Comment: No, not Xen - but the link to the Spice instructions work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Removing or disabling Apparmor should solve your problem if it's caused by apparmor

[Disable and remove AppArmor on Ubuntu based Linux distributions](http://www.techytalk.info/disable-and-remove-apparmor-on-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions/)

For me it solved many problems especially with upstream compiled kernel and I haven't noticed any downside to this approach. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

View also :-

http://bderzhavets.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/implementation-spice-on-ubuntu-11-10-kvm-server-the-most-recent-approach/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

View PPA :

Qemu&Spice USB Redirection and Libvirt 0.9.6 on Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)

https://launchpad.net/~bderzhavets/+archive/lib-usbredir19

"Howto" :

http://bderzhavets.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/usb-redirection-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.